# How to add partitions to Kafka in Go?

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I want to add partitions to an existing topic. Like the [alter](https://www.allprogrammingtutorials.com/tutorials/adding-partitions-to-topic-in-apache-kafka.php) command, but I want to do that from my Go application.

- [segmentio/kafka-go](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go) is the most popular and my preferred Kafka library, but it doesn't look like the library supports this.
- [confluent-kafka-go](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go) and [sarama](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama) lacks support for [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/).
- [goka](https://github.com/lovoo/goka) has a pretty specific usage pattern and I'm not entirely sure if it supports altering topics.

This seems like a common use case but doesn't look like it's commonly supported. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's really hard to compose an answer without knowing your context. Anyway, it's not a good practice to add partitions from your applications. Are you writing a management tool for Kafka? If it's not,  you can use one of the Kafka management tools available outthere.

Comment: Here's a synonymous use case: My application receives blockchain entries from a set of nodes. Because entries are unique per node and node may choose to join me whenever, I want to create an unique partitions for each node as they join. If adding partitions is a bad practice, then how about creating a topic for each node?